# How to solve the subquery

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I have data like this

```
Sr_No/ AccessionNo  / Roll_nO   / Price
---------------------------------------    
1  /     101     /      45   /     1000
2  /     102        /   46     /   2000
3   /    101       /    43    /    500
```

I have written this query

```
select * 
from Circulation 
where MAX(sr_no) in (select * 
                     from circulation 
                     where accessionno = @accessionno)
```

I want to get values where the accession no is given by the textbox and it should be the the maximum value of `Sr_No` and for info `Sr_NO` is auto incremented.

My query is not working

I am a student and started c# quite a few months ago

Sorry for my bad english

I got this error

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE
>   clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the 
>   column being aggregated is an outer reference.
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

I want that when I type 101 as accession no. so it will return this info

```
3   /    101       /    43    /    500
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably wanted something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Circulation 
WHERE sr_no = (SELECT MAX(sr_no)
               FROM circulation 
               WHERE accessionno = @accessionno)
```

You want to select the row(s) from `Circulation` where the `sr_no` column equals the maximum of all `sr_no` values in your table - right?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a TOP 1 for this rather than a nested SELECT? Using the ORDER BY and TOP 1 does this same thing and has an improved execution plan.

Comment: @AlexS.: depends on whether you really want only the first row with the top value - or maybe you want **all rows** that have the max value? Then `TOP 1` would not be appropriate.

Comment: @marc_s: Correct. In this case, SR_No auto increments so there should not be a case where multiple rows will be returned. Really, it's splitting hairs since they both do the same thing given the data set the asker is working with.

Answer (score 1):

`SQL Server` supports *Common Table Expression* and *Window Function*. `ROW_NUMBER()` will rank the `SR_NO` in descending order for every `AccessionNo`. So the value of `1` is given for the highest `SR_NO` per `AccessionNo`.

```
WITH records
AS
(
    SELECT  Sr_No, AccessionNo, Roll_nO, Price,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AccessionNo ORDER BY Sr_No DESC) rn
    FROM    Circulation 
)
SELECT  Sr_No, AccessionNo, Roll_nO, Price
FROM    records
WHERE   rn = 1
```

But if an `AccessionNo` is already give, a simple `TOP` will do your job.

```
SELECT   TOP 1 * 
FROM     Circulation 
WHERE    accessionno = @accessionno
ORDER BY Sr_no DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM Circulation 
WHERE accessionno = @accessionno
ORDER BY Sr_no DESC
```

Also, it's best not to use SELECT * and instead use the column names.